# Pillow - cannot save resized/cropped gif

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am using the `Pillow` package to change some gifs to animated .webp's with a square size.
The issue is that the saved file isn't resized/cropped.
This is my code:

```py
destination = Path(source).with_suffix(".webp")
extension = ".webp"
        
im = Image.open(source)
width, height = im.size
          
if width != height:
  if width > height:
    left = (width - height)/2
    top = 0
    right = (width + height)/2
    bottom = height
  else:
    left = 0
    top = (height - width)/2
    right = width
    bottom = (height + width)/2

  if getattr(im, "is_animated", False):
    frames = ImageSequence.Iterator(im)
    cropped_frames = []
  
    for frame in frames:
      cropped_frames.append(frame.crop((left, top, right, bottom))) 

    im.save(destination, format="webp", save_all=True, optimize=True, append_images=list(frames), loop=0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want to do this?

save `cropped_frames` not `frames`

```
im.save(destination, format="webp", save_all=True, optimize=True, append_images=cropped_frames, loop=0)
```